# 2 ajax calls at the same time causing issues in views

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm using [django-el-pagination](http://django-el-pagination.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multiple_pagination.html#adding-ajax-for-multiple-pagination) to render 2 querysets (`Post` and `Comment`) with ajax. So when I click `more posts` or `more comments`, it loads the next batch of objects in the respective queryset. Here is the JS function showing this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.endless_more', function() {
    console.log($(this).html());
    var user_queryset;
    if ($(this).html() === 'more posts') {
        console.log('POSTS');
        user_queryset = 'user_posts'
    } else if ($(this).html() === 'more user comments') {
        user_queryset = 'user_comments';
        console.log('COMMENTS');
    } else {
        console.log('none');
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: window.location.href,
        data: {
            'user_queryset': user_queryset
        }

    })
});
```

and here is the view which receives the data from the function (`user_posts` or `user_comments` depending on what was clicked).

```
def profile(request, user, extra_context=None):
    ...
    page_template = 'profile/profile.html'
    print('LOAD')

    if request.is_ajax():
        print('Requests:', request.GET)
        user_queryset = request.GET.get('user_queryset')

        print('Queryset:', user_queryset)
        if user_queryset == 'user_posts':
            page_template = 'profile/user_posts.html'
        elif user_queryset == 'user_comments':
            page_template = 'profile/user_comments.html'
        elif user_queryset == 'user_inbox':
            page_template = 'profile/user_inbox.html'
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass

    print('Template:', page_template)

    context = {'user_posts': user_posts,
                'user_comments': user_comments, 'page_template': page_template}

    return render(request, page_template, context)
```

Now, the JS works fine - it sends the correct data depending on what was clicked. So the `page_template` in the view is successfully updated during the ajax call, however it renders the parent template (`profile.html`) instead of the chosen child template (`user_posts.html` or `user_comments.html`). The reason for this may be because there are 2 ajax calls being sent at the same time - one from `django-el-pagination` and one from my JS function. I know there are 2 calls because of my print statements. Firstly, when I first load the whole page here are my print statements:

```
LOAD
Template: profile/profile.html
```

this is correct - it loads the parent template.

Now here are my print statements when I click on `more posts`:

```
LOAD
Requests: <QueryDict: {'querystring_key': ['page'], 'page': ['2']}>
Queryset: None
Template: profile/profile.html
LOAD
Requests: <QueryDict: {'user_queryset': ['user_posts']}>
Queryset: user_posts
Template: profile/user_posts.html
```

as you can see it goes through my view twice. Why does it do this? The first time it gets the pagination data, then the next time it gets the clicked button (in this instance `user_posts`). Even though it gets called twice, the 2nd time has the correct template to load (`user_posts.html`), so it should still work - but it doesn't, it still loads the parent template. Do anyone have any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it? I don't think there is anything wrong which the actual code; if I change it to `user_queryset = 'user_posts'` in my `request.is_ajax()` then it works fine - only loading the `user_posts.html`. However it can't seem to deal with the having two querysets.

Comment: Side note: To verify how many and which XHR get executed you should inspect your browsers developer tools (network tab) first. Inspecting the server side should be the second step.

Comment: Here's an image of all the XHR requests (as expected, the 2 ajax requests in my question are there at the top): https://i.imgur.com/YHTfGgu.png - does this tell you anything?